# How to check empty resultset in idiorm by using find_one()

Tags: php, resultset, idiorm

I'm searching couple of hours in google for find a solution but not found yet. So, I'm asking at the end. I have simple query. I need to check query return a result or not. Here it is:

```
$content = ORM::for_table("pages")->where("deleted",0)->find_one($id);
if ($content->count() > 0) {
... do something
}
```

Above code block returns below error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on boolean.....
```

How do I check if result set has rows or not ?

Comment: `if ($content) { ...` ?

Comment: Oh my God :( I'm so silly. It worked.

Comment: I think I need rest. :/ Thanks for your help :)